# Shape of passed values does not coincide with indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to concatenate 3 dataframes by columns:

```
myList = [ta.append(tb), pd.DataFrame(numpy_a).append(pd.DataFrame(numpy_b)), pd.DataFrame(numpy_c).append(pd.DataFrame(numpy_d))]

merged = pd.concat(myList,axis=1)
```

Then I get the error:

```
Shape of passed values is (12, 388), indices imply (12, 222)
```

I checked that the length of each dataframe is equal to 222.

```
len(ta.append(tb))
len(pd.DataFrame(numpy_a).append(pd.DataFrame(numpy_b)))
len(pd.DataFrame(numpy_c).append(pd.DataFrame(numpy_d)))
```

So, why do I still get this error?

Comment: Overlapping default column names?  You probably can fix by giving column names, or instead do a numpy concat.  Also, try pairwise concat instead of 3 at once to narrow it down.  You haven't provided sample data, so hard to do anything more than speculate.

Comment: @JohnE: Thanks. It has been helpful.